# How to calculate equation of plane

Tags: geometry

> A plane passes through the point $\langle4, 5, 7\rangle + s\langle7, 8, 1\rangle + t\langle4, 1, 6\rangle$. What is the equation of plane?

My solution.

$$n_1= \langle7, 8, 1\rangle, n_2=\langle4, 1, 6\rangle, n_3= \langle7, 8, 1,\rangle*\langle4, 1, 6\rangle=(47, -38, -25)$$

Equation of the plane,
$$47(x-4)+(-38)(y-5)+(-25)(z-7)=0$$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: What you wrote is not a point, but the parametric form of a plane.